# Finding the values in an array that have the most occurrences

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have an array of tags taken from a MySQL database. Obviously, these tags are strings and are stored in an array, with one element in the array storing each tag. TO build my tag cloud, I want to be able to count the occurrences of each tag to find the most common tag.

For example, if I have the table below...

```
tag1
tag1
hi
bye
gnu
tux
tag1
tux
tux
tag1
...
etc
```

... the most commonly occurring tag is "tag1" what I want to do is count how many times that tag occurs in the array. `Max()` doesn't help here due to it only liking numerical values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use array_count_values

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>


Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

if you do not want the case-sensitive version use :

```
$ar = array_count_values(array_map('strtolower', $ar));
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you could have your database perform all the heavy lifting for you. Sounds like you are getting an array of tags, maybe like this

```
SELECT tag FROM mytable;
```

But you could do this

```
SELECT tag,count(*) AS occurrences FROM mytable 
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY occurences;
```

Hey presto, a list of tags and their frequency!

Comment: actually the tags are stored as a CSV list in the database, but yeah I do get an array of them - `explode()` comes in very handy! (PHP)

Comment: Also, I used the solution I marked correct, but when the time comes to have a good rewrite fest, I will definitely use this method - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you array is like this

```
$array = array('tag1','tag1','hi','bye','gnu','tux','tag1','tux','tux','tag1');

$arrayCounting = array_count_values($array));
```

will give you an array like this to work with

```
Array
(
    [tag1] => 4
    [hi] => 1
    [bye] => 1
    [gnu] => 1
    [tux] => 3
)
```

Comment: What if you don't know what the array elements are?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean http://stackoverflow.com/users/5294439/michael-ozoemena this technique is not restricted to knowing values

Comment: Forget that. Using this method how can I get the content of the most occurring element in the array. How can I get it to output "tag1" having in mind that I don't know about the existence of "tag1".